# How to run a script without being in the tasktray?

Tags: python

I have a scheduled task which runs a python script every 10 min

so it turns out that a script pops up on my desktop every 10 min

how can i make it invincible so my script will work in the background ?

I've been told that pythonw will do the work, but I cant figure out how to use it

any help ?
thanks

Comment: Making it invisible can be done. Making it invincible will take a fair bit of effort :-)

Answer (score 3):

> I've been told that pythonw will do the work, but I cant figure out how to use it

Normally you just have to rename the file extension to .pyw. Then it will be executed by pythonw.

Answer (score 0):

Set the scheduled task to start the script as minimized.